# how do i change the back button title in a view controller pushed with a segue as below in ios5

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

using the code below i am opening an information screen.
everything works fine, the screen opens and the title is shown as i want, however i can not get the default back button title to change

how should i do it in xcode5

thanks

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"infoRegularSegue"])
    {


        FirstViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Information", title of information     view);

//this code below does not work      
  destViewController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"test";

//ive also tried leftbuttonitem

    }
}
```

Comment: add self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.title = @"test"; statement in viewDidLayoutSubviews function in destination controller and check... i have not test it but it should work...

Comment: sorry but this does'nt work either

Comment: possible duplicate of [set title of back bar button item in ios](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17403483/set-title-of-back-bar-button-item-in-ios)

Answer (score 7):

after a lot of searching and trying various solutions on this forum, i finally got something that works which i am posting below for the benefit of others that get stuck at this point.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"infoRegularSegue"])
    {


        FirstViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        destViewController.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Information", title of information view);

        //here is the solution to my problem
        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Return", returnbuttontitle) style:     UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;

    }
}
```